# A for loop in forms.py fails to load data immediately after it's sent | Python Django

Tags: python, django

In the forms.py I have a short piece of code which loads the data, but only after I edit `print("hello")` in it.

The code as follows:

`models.py`:

```
class CreateAssignment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)
    progress = models.CharField(max_length=254, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)

class SetAssignment(models.Model):
    mechanic = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)
    assignment = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The mechanic is a permission, plus this mechanic's ID will show in the url of the website, when you will try to set an assignment for this mechanic.

`forms.py`:

```
class SetAssignmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ASSIGNMENT_CHOICES = ()

    for item in CreateAssignment.objects.all():
        if item.progress == 'Scheduling':
            user = User.objects.get(id=item.user_id).username

            ASSIGNMENT_CHOICES += (
                (item.id, user + ' - ' + str(item.id)),
            )

    assignment = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ASSIGNMENT_CHOICES, help_text='This is the assignment that you want to apply to this mechanic.')

    class Meta:
        model = SetAssignment
        fields = ('assignment', )
```

The `user_id` in this situation is the `user` that has been set in the `CreateAssignment` model.

Now the issue is:

- The `for` loop in the `SetAssignmentForm` works, but it loads data after I put a `print` in it or when I remove the `print` from it. Which of course shouldn't really affect the code.

Is there something I'm overlooking? I've been programming in Python Django for 8 weeks now, so if this is a basic program failure, please refer me to a page, because I haven't been able to find any information on this issue.

Thanks for the help.

For the ones that want to know:

`views.py`:

```
@login_required
def set_assignment(request):
    form = SetAssignmentForm()
    id = request.GET.get('id')
    user_results = User.objects.filter(pk=id).values()
    return render(request, 'pages/set_assignment.html', {'form': form, 'user_results': user_results})
```

Gif so you can visually see what's happening:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u7gfdiS7KitQWNVuvQEEOFJ9wD3q9rY6

Comment: You almost certainly want to be using `ModelChoiceField`, not `ChoiceField`. Your loop will only run when the class is defined, not on each form creation, so as written your choices will only be those `CreateAssignment` instances in the database when Django starts.

Comment: Here you are returning a QuerySet: `User.objects.filter(pk=id)`. How many users do you expect to have with the same id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not write code like this at class level. Anything at that level is only executed once, at definition time - ie when the class is first imported.

If you need to make the values dynamic, you should put the logic inside the `__init__` method:

```
class SetAssignmentForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    assignment = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], help_text='This is the assignment that you want to apply to this mechanic.')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SetAssignmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        items = CreateAssignment.objects.filter(progress='Scheduling').select_related('user')
        choices = [(item.id, '{} - {}'.format(item.id, item.user.username)) for item in items]
        self.fields['assignment'].choices = choices
```

(Note, your query logic was very inefficient; my code only hits the database one time.)

However, here you don't even need to do that, because Django already has a form field - ModelChoiceField - that takes its values from the database. You can use a custom subclass of that to show the representation:

```
class AssignmentField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, item):
        return (item.id, '{} - {}'.format(item.id, item.user.username))

class SetAssignmentForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    assignment = forms.AssignmentField(queryset=CreateAssignment.objects.filter(progress='Scheduling').select_related('user'))
```

Comment: Thanks, your explenation fixed it for me, really interesting, haven't really worked a lot with `__init__` yet, definitely something I want to look further into now. Also I didn't know yet that you could make your own fields. Thanks for these interesting solutions.